# Find and get content from .txt files in a specific folder, Android Studio

Tags: android, file, bluetooth, find

I'm creating an app that will find all the .txt files in the bluetooth folder of my phone, open the files, get a certain content (a date and a runtime).

The computer sends the .txt files to the phone over bluetooth, and then the app should inspect that folder.

What kind of function can i use to find, open and analyse all the files?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, get the directory you want to search:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/bluetooth";
File directory = new File(path);
```

Now you can get a list of files like this

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Now we iterate through each file to see if its a .txt file

```
StringBuilder text = new Stringbuilder;
for (File f : files)
{
   if (f.isFile() && f.getpath().endswith(".txt")) { 
    //it is a txt file, now do your action
    try {
        //read file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String line;
        br.readLine();
        //read each line
        while ((line = br.readLine())) {
            //Write your conditions here
            //add line to stringbuilder
            text.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
    }
   }
}
```

Add this for permission if running on Android M or up

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            }, 10);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have checked this solution and and i get a Null Pointer exception,

from the system prints I get that the path is is:

/storage/emulated/0/bluetooth

and from

'code' (File[] files = directory.listFiles();)

I get null. 

The bluetooth folder of my phone currently contains 12 text files, so it should pick up something. Could it be finding the wrong folder?

Comment: The documentation for the listFiles() method clearly states that it "Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.". Also check if you have the permission to READ STORAGE. If you are using Android M and above, you must ask for permission during runtime also.

Comment: I have written     in the manifest    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 and nothing changes

Comment: Check edited answer

Comment: Now it gets stuck into a loop, and keeps trying to read the files. Should i also place  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />  in the manifest?   Minimum SDK is 15 and my phone is using API 25

Comment: Yea, you have to provide permission in manifest also

Comment: I did and problem remains the same.

Comment: By the way, the bluetooth folder is placed in the internal storage, not the SD card.

Comment: I can only give you the syntax. Please change it to accommodate your needs